# Is the following matrix orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I am told this matrix is supposed to be orthogonal, but when I multiply it by itself (its transpose), I get 7/4 on the diagonal and not 1. Does an orthogonal matrix have to be 1's on the diagonal?

\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\\ -\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}&-\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}

Comment: I think you want $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$

Comment: Thank you. That's definitely it. The textbook has the fraction set up horizontal so it is tougher to see that the denominator is not included in the radicand.